# face recognition opencv assertion failed

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, compiler-errors

I am writing a face recognition code using opencv, and it returns an error at this line every time I run it.

This is the line of my code:

```
small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx=0.5, fy=0.5, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

The error it throws:

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.2)
>   /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp:3720: error: (-215:Assertion
>   failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'resize'

I think I could solve it if I can find this file named `resize.cpp`, but I don't know how to do it either.

Comment: I think you should provide size of the new image in place of None , check the link https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.tutorialkart.com/opencv/python/opencv-python-resize-image/ , it is mandatory to provide new shape

Comment: @manojyadav i have tried it using (0,0) but it is showing same error then also.

Comment: Try (50,50) for just checking , (0,0) is not valida size I think

Comment: Hello Satyam! Welcome to the community. I just edited your code a little bit in order to help avoiding any negative points to your question.

Comment: Thank you @mantingablue for your help.

Comment: Welcome, Satyam :-) 
I don't really know why would anyone downvote this question, also without saying the reason and to a newcomer. Didn't Karlphilip's answer help?

Comment: it really helped @MaríaAntignolo. thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome, I'm glad it helped :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error means that `frame` is empty. There is no image!

```
if (frame is None):
    print('!!! EMPTY IMAGE')
    sys.exit(0)

small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx=0.5, fy=0.5, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
```